# Is using docker compose to architect microservices on one machine a bad idea?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

If I have an application made up of microservices A, B and C - I could construct these as containers within docker compose however does that violate the point of separating out the services? Two advantages of microservices are scaling each service independently and isolating any server crash to one service - if I use docker compose just on one server surely if the host machine goes down then all my services do and also if I want to scale one service I have to scale up (or down) the whole machine. How do I get around this? Should I use docker-compose to compose several containers needed on one machine, like its application layer and database layer? then rinse repeat?

Comment: I think there are several ways to accomplish a safe infrastructure. I'd treat every microservice with its own docker compose. You surely have all the microservices in seperate git repositories so it's a good bet to have a docker compose file for each. A microservice might consist of several servers, like a database, a cache instance and the application code. Scaling on production can be seperated from starting up the containers on your local machine for development.

Comment: Using Compose on a single host with a small number of services makes total sense for a development or test setup.  Kubernetes is arguably the most popular tool for running multiple replicas of containers on a cluster of nodes, but it is significantly more complex than plain Compose.  Somewhere like [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask more specific deployment-mechanics questions.

Comment: @DanielW. Thank you I think that's also the way to go - there's just some misleading tutorials for microservices that lead you to believe you should keep your services all in one compose file (implying the same machine... i think?) - I'll leave this question for some discussion but accept this as an answer if no one objects and you post it as one.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't think that answers my questions, doesn't using one machine introduce the problems I specified?

Comment: Plain Compose won't work on a single host.  That's where you need a cluster infrastructure like Kubernetes or Docker Swarm, or to hand-build something built around a service-discovery tool like Consul.  You're right, and putting all of your infrastructure on a single unreplicated node is probably bad, but I'm not sure if you have a more specific question we can try to answer.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have docker compose working on one host right now running nginx, postgres and php for me - i just needed to add a golang service and a few others and was wondering if it would be better to not include them in the compose file (on the single host) and instead run them on seperate servers accordingly. I think that your help and the comment from Daniel W. answers my question - it may have been too vague for SO and more appropriate for the devops one. I'm happy to accept an answer here though if Daniel posts his comment as one.

Comment: @DavidMaze that's not true information, and the opposite is the case: Compose works best on a single host.

Comment: ...wow, I _did_ say that totally wrong.  Plain Compose _only_ works on a single host; it doesn't work on _multiple_ hosts and that's where you need cluster infrastructure.

Comment: @DavidMaze hehe, happens :D I think we both gave OP good input to progress with the work. Nice day fellas!